# Suppressing/Programmatically click through error messages on msi install

Tags: inno-setup, windows-installer

I'm using Inno Setup to run an external installer using

```
Params := '/i '+ExpandConstant('{tmp}\BDE.msi')+' /s BDE="'+ExpandConstant('{pf}\Common Files\Borland Shared\BDE')+'"';
Exec('msiexec.exe', Params, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

Ideally, I'd like to eventually be able to pass the `/passive` option and have just a progress bar install. However, there is a useless error message that pops up during installation.

[image: BDE Merge fail, except I don't care]

Is there a way, either via Inno Setup or via Msiexec, to click-through that message?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround-if you install with admin privileges you won't ever run into that error message. Doesn't answer my question, but works for now.